# Connect to external database (mysql) with python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am trying to connect to my website's MySQL database from my own computer. The script I use:

```
hostaddress = 'sitedezign.net'
username = '*********'
password = '*********'
database = '*********'
db_port = 3306

#connect
db = _mysql.connect(host=hostaddress,user=username,passwd=password,db=database, port=db_port)
```

However I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Yorian\Desktop\TU\Stage Shore\python_files\Rectify, metadata and upload\sql_test.py", line 25, in <module>
port=db_port)
OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'sitedezign.net' (10061)")
```

- I have switched my computer's firewall off and also added an outbound rule to my firewall for when I connect to an outbound port 3306 (to allow this)
- The user does have the rights, I've tested this by running a php script with the same login data on the server and it connects perfectly fine (host=localhost)
- I set the server to allow external connections coming from my IP address (IPv4 as well as IPV6)

The server is from a webhoster so I can not access the server myself.

Anybody that has an idea where things are going wrong?

Comment: Are you using same connectionstring as ur using in php script like port and other info?. The error (2003) Can't connect to MySQL server on 'server' (10061) indicates that the network connection has been refused. You should check that there is a MySQL server running, that it has network connections enabled, and that the network port you specified is the one configured on the server..

Comment: Maybe you can ask the webhoster, seems MySQL server doesn't accept the connection from outside.
There is a config file of MySQL that can set the listen ip but I don't if you have the right to set this.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried it from a different location and it worked. I think the problem was the router, I think that still had a firewall.